# Searching for String inside another (with interruptions), on Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to check whether the main string contains the entire substring, even if there are interruptions.

For example:

- main string = `12ab34cd`,
- substring = `1234d`

should return a positive, since `1234d` is entirely contained in my main string, even though there are extra characters.

Since `InStr` doesn't take wildcards, I wrote my own VBA using the `mid` function, which works well if there are extra characters at the start/end, but not with extra characters in the middle.

In the above example, the function I wrote

- works if the main string is `ab1234dc`,
- but not if it's `12ab34cd`.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do using VBA?

Comment: wheres your code.

Comment: Your best bet is probably Regex.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: [Regular Expressions]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) are definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** Both of the methods below are case sensitive.  To make them case insensitive, you can either use `Ucase` (or `Lcase`) to create phrases with the same case, or you can prefix the routine with the `Option Compare Text` statement.

Although this can be done with regular expressions, here's a method using `Mid` and `Instr`

```
Option Explicit
Function ssFind(findStr, mainStr) As Boolean
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

I = 1: J = 1
Do Until I > Len(findStr)
    J = InStr(J, mainStr, Mid(findStr, I, 1))
    If J = 0 Then
        ssFind = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    I = I + 1: J = J + 1
Loop
ssFind = True

End Function
```

Actually, you can shorten the code further using `Like`:

```
Option Explicit
Function ssFind(findStr, mainStr) As Boolean
    Dim I As Long
    Dim S As String

For I = 1 To Len(findStr)
    S = S & "*" & Mid(findStr, I, 1)
Next I
S = S & "*"

ssFind = mainStr Like S
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 3 columns "SUBSTR","MAIN" and "CHECK" and your "Substring" data range is named "SUBSTR"

```
Sub check_char()

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("SUBSTR")
    a = 1
    test = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(c.Offset(0, 1))
        If Mid(c.Offset(0, 1), i, 1) = Mid(c, a, 1) Then
            test = test & Mid(c.Offset(0, 1), i, 1)
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Next i
    If test = c Then
        c.Offset(0, 2) = "MATCH"
    Else
        c.Offset(0, 2) = "NO MATCH"
    End If
Next
```

End Sub